# showing causality between police killings and demographics (i.e. race, class, gender, location)

Tags: correlation, classification, causality, bayesian-network

I've got a whole lot of police data and was wondering what sort of approaches I could use to show strong correlation, and if possible, causal effects, between police killings/arrest & call-ins for petty-crimes and class/race/gender/location (which is itself connected to class/race).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hot issue in US at the moment.  Need to be careful about "selective reporting" in terms of what actually gets written down by police officers.  For example, how are 'warnings' handled?  Are they recorded?  Probably not consistently across police departments.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate statistical associations or causal effects?

Comment: @probabilityislogic This is true. I think it's safe to conclude something the police actually define as petty, like marijuana possession, is in fact petty. Could get messy for things like resisting arrest, assault, etc. Also, we are only using one city's police data

Comment: @MatthewGunn we'd like to estimate actual causal effects.

Comment: If you're trying to estimate the causal effect of $x$ on $y$, what do you have in mind for $x$ and $y$? What is $x$? What is $y$? The tricky issue is that to estimate a causal effect, you need some exogenous variation in $x$, variation in $x$ that is linked to $y$ *only* through the causal channel you are trying to investigate.

Comment: @MatthewGunn oops sorry for the slow response. Say x is class and y is eviction. If we have heaps of data with things like race, age, location and seemingly insignificant variables like height constant, we can test changes in class and see if eviction rates increase, right? But is that even enough to prove something is causal? Or can we measure certainty of it being causal?

Comment: @Imlirak With race, it's hard to implement the classic, randomized controlled experiment. You can't change someone's race and see what else changes (Exception: some studies look at job applications with everything the same except an African American sounding name vs. white sounding name). Instead in the racial discrimination context, people establish some correlation between race and outcomes and then try to argue causal effects by ruling out rational, non-racial discrimination stories. Eg. I recently heard a talk on: http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/workshops/finance/pdf/HBCU_JAN_17_2015.pdf